# IntelliJ not providing option to convert class to record

Tags: intellij-idea, java-record

I have a large set of POJO classes (100+) that I would like to convert to Java records. I would like to automate the process.

I am on Java 18 (Amazon Coretto JDK) and IntelliJ 2022.1.4 (Ultimate Edition): `Build #IU-221.6008.13, built on July 18, 2022`

`coretto-18` is configured to be module's default VM.

I followed the IntelliJ documentation (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/convert-to-record/), but the Context Actions on won't show the option "Convert to a record" (expected).

[image]

Comment: In the example you linked the fields are `final`, your fields are not. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Records are immutable - all their fields are `final`. "Convert to a record" in the Context Actions doesn't show up because your class isn't equivalent to a record. To get it, make all fields `final` or change `@Data` to its immutable version `@Value`.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Inspections -> Class Can Be A Record

Removed `javax.*` from *Suppress conversion if class is annotated by*